# 3D Interaction when using CDFDeploy

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, cdf-format

In the following code, the 3D plot of the manipulation is interactive.

```
Manipulate[
 Button["Plot", plot = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^0], {x, -3, 3}, {y,-2, 2}]], 
 Dynamic[plot], 
 Initialization :> (
    plot = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
)]
```

However, when I deploy it as a CDF, the interaction with 3D object is lost. Why is this happening.

```
CDFDeploy[
    "111.cdf",
    Manipulate[
       Button["Plot", plot = Plot3D[Sin[x +y^0], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]], 
       Dynamic[plot], 
       Initialization :> (
          plot = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
)]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have put the `plot` to the second argument of `Manipulate`, while there are some examples around with different things there it is really meant only for controllers.

So what you have to do is to gather your output in the first argument of `Manipulate`, with a `Grid` or something:

```
[...]
Column[{
  Button["Plot", plot = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^0], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]],
  Dynamic[plot]
}]
[...]
```

will do.